# Attaching a base64_encoded string in emails - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've spent the last day creating a script that will create a PDF-receipt when a customer buys something from our site. When the PDF is created, I save the output to a variable using [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

I then make this variable into a base64_encoded string. When I'm done doing that, I save the string to a database. Now, what I want to do after that is get the string and in some way save it as an attachment to an email, so that the user can download it as a file. I've tried Google, but I didn't find anything helpful really.

I found this thread, but as far as I can see in the Codeigniter email-library (I might have missed it), the requested function wasn't implemented. Here is the request though, [Email class: add attachment from string](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/89686/#452473)

Comment: There are 3rd party email libraries that handles attachments, html mail etc for you, like SwiftMailer, phpmailer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own library and send the email using the php mail function and the appropriate headers.

```
function send_email($to, $from, $subject, $body, $attachment_string)
{

$filename = "receipt.pdf";
$uid = md5(uniqid(time())); 
$attachment=chunk_split($attachment_string);

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from.">\r\n";
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $body."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".basename($filename)."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= $attachment."\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$uid."--";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
{
    echo "success";
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter Email class, when we pass mime type as an argument the following code executes.

```
$file_content =& $file; // buffered file

$this->_attachments[] = array(
        'name'      => array($file, $newname),
        'disposition'   => empty($disposition) ? 'attachment' :    $disposition,  // Can also be 'inline'  Not sure if it matters
        'type'      => $mime,
        'content'   => chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content)),
        'multipart' => 'mixed'
    );
```

`chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content))`  will break the base64 file that we passed to `$this->email->attach()` function.

So that I changed the code to

```
    $file_content =& $file; // buffered file
    $file_content = ($this->_encoding == 'base64') ? $file_content   :  chunk_split(base64_encode($file_content));
```

Now attachment array as:

```
 $this->_attachments[] = array(
        'name'      => array($file, $newname),
        'disposition'   => empty($disposition) ? 'attachment' :  $disposition,  // Can also be 'inline'  Not sure if it matters
        'type'      => $mime,
        'content'   => $file_content,
        'multipart' => 'mixed'
    );
```

Now when I intialzed email with :

```
   $config['_bit_depths'] = array('7bit', '8bit','base64');
   $config['_encoding'] = 'base64'
   $this->load->library('email',$config);
```

May be I'm doing the wrong way, but it works.

```
   $this->email->attach($base64,'attachment','report.pdf','application/pdf');
```

Download modified email class:

https://github.com/aqueeel/CI-Base64EmailAttach